# Redis-OM library error during next js redis implementations

Tags: next.js, redis, node-redis

I need some help to figure it our why I am getting error when using macthes API, this is my code:

```
export async function searchCars(query) {
  await connect();

  const repository = client.fetchRepository(schema);

  const cars = await repository
    .search()
    .where("make")
    .eq(query)
    .or("model")
    .eq(query)
    .or("description")
    .matches(query)
    .return.all();

  return cars;
}
```

And I am getting this error when making API request

[image]

May I ask for help?

Many thanks ~~

I did remove the `macthes()` API, the whole query works, and I can get results back.
If i add it back, the APi will return redis error ...

Expectation: I would like to do text search which matches the paragraph text, then return the record(s).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think I have figured it our, the issue is we need to ensure the scheme field type must be `text` rather than `string`, something like below:

```
description: { type: "text", textSearch: true },
```